# beeline query to Spark Thrift Server not showing anything in Spark History UI

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, beeline, spark-thriftserver

I just built a Hortonworks cluster with Hive and Spark Thrift Server on port 10016 (default) and tested SELECT statement via beeline to STS

https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/sql-programming-guide.html#running-the-thrift-jdbcodbc-server

```
beeline> !connect jdbc:hive2://localhost:10016/default
select * from table1;
```

I could get the results and everything is fine. But my question is how come the queries don't show up in Spark History Server UI at all? How do I know if it's actually Spark doing the computation work vs. pass thru HiveServer2?

**UPDATE 1**

This is what I have and log is already enabled by default:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are using connection with port 10016 - it's Spark. 
Please check property **spark.eventLog.enabled** is set to **true** (it have to be in $SPARK_HOME/conf/spark-defaults.conf).

Comment: I added my screenshot above. Thanks.